Secret env vars break the NextJS build on Netlify
My NextJS build on Netlify is failing because of secret environment variables.
My app interacts with the Spotify API. I need to set secrets for both Spotify and NextAuth.
Those vars were created on Netlify and marked as secret.
My code only references them in several places through variables like the ones below, they are never hard-coded. On my local, those variables are on the .env file and on Netliffy they are set up on the control panel.
    clientId: process.env.SPOTIFY_CLIENT_ID!,
    clientSecret: process.env.SPOTIFY_CLIENT_SECRET!,
    secret: process.env.NEXTAUTH_SECRET,

The errors on the build look like this:

Secrets scanning found 97 instance(s) of secrets in build output or repo code. Secret env var “SPOTIFY_CLIENT_SECRET”'s value detected

I experimented with it and ran the build locally. Then I searched for the value of those keys in the .next folder and found 8 occurrences of the value in 6 files. However I do not know if those files are accessible publicly. These are the files:
/.next/required-server-files.json
/.next/standalone/.next/required-server-files.json
/.next/server/app/api/auth/[...nextauth]/route.js
/.next/standalone/.next/server/app/api/auth/[...nextauth]/route.js
/.next/standalone/.env
/.next/standalone/server.js

So my two questions are:

Can the files above be accessed publicly?

Netlify has documentation about certain variables we can use so these secret variables are ignored. But what is the point of setting them as secret and then ignoring them? Why would I bother setting them as secrets in the first place?`


I want my secret vars to remain secret.

Short answer: clear Netlify cache and see Solution
Long answer: what likely happened is that Netlify found references to your secret vars in its cache. That's because you pushed your code to git before defining the Secret Environment Variables on Netlify. When building for your git push, Netlify cached references to your Secret vars which were not secret to Netlify yet.
Solution: Netlify project > Published deploy > Retry or Options > Clear cache and retry commit with latest branch

Hi Joey, I tried it again, but no luck. I believe what it's trying to say is that these secrets will end up in JS-compiled code.
Netilify's help:


Verify that the detected secrets (AUTH_SECRET, GRAPHQL_ENDPOINT, SITE_URL, SPOTIFY_CLIENT_ID, SPOTIFY_CLIENT_SECRET, WP_API) should not be exposed.


If these secrets are expected, use SECRETS_SCAN_OMIT_PATHS, SECRETS_SCAN_OMIT_KEYS, or SECRETS_SCAN_ENABLED to prevent them from being detected.


If I add the 'secret' flag to a variable and then use those workarounds to make them ignored, what is the point of adding the 'secret' flag?
